# FirstViewController does not conform to Protocol

Tags: ios

I wrote this in  Xcode 6 (Swift) but it says "Type 'FirstViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'" and won't let me build the program. Please help?

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//UIViewTableDataSource
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
   return taskMGR.tasks.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) ->
    UITableViewCell!{



        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:
            "test")

        cell.textLabel?.text = taskMGR.tasks[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = taskMGR.tasks[indexPath.row].desc

        return cell
}

}
```

Comment: You lack `override` in front of those two dataSource methods...

Comment: Also: Instead of conforming to `UIViewController`, `UITableViewDelegate` & `UITableViewDataSource` you might as well make the class a subclass of `UITableViewController`...

Comment: set data source and delegate programatically in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your class to work.  I deleted a couple of **variables** I did not need, but you can add them back.  Key was to delete '`UITableViewDataSource`' (you do not conform to this) and to unwrap the optional  cell the way you wrote it.  I prefer not to construct the cell that way, but that is another discussion.  If you still have issues let me know.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//UIViewTableDataSource
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) ->
    UITableViewCell!{

        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:
            "test")!

        return cell
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comments you might as well change the class to a `UITableViewController` subclass as it is basically the same as `UIViewController` + `UITableViewDelegate` + `UITableViewDataSource` (with a *little* bit of extra functionality included if you want it). It also has a UITableView property included "out of the box".

You will then end up with the following class:

```
class FirstViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //UIViewTableDataSource
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return taskMGR.tasks.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
            let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"test")
            cell.textLabel?.text = taskMGR.tasks[indexPath.row].name // You can remove ? when updating to XCode 6.1 / Swift 1.1
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = taskMGR.tasks[indexPath.row].desc
            return cell
    }
}
```